# Write function in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to understand a VHDL code. Here it is :

```
  procedure write_reg (L : inout line; reg : reg_index) is

  begin
    write(L, 'R');
    write(L, reg);
  end write_reg;

 when sp_func_movi2s =>
            write_special_reg(L, Rtype_rd); write(L, string'(", "));
            write_reg(L, rs1);
          when sp_func_movs2i =>
            write_reg(L, Rtype_rd); write(L, string'(", "));
            write_special_reg(L, rs1);
          when sp_func_movf | sp_func_movd =>
            write_freg(L, Rtype_rd); write(L, string'(", "));
            write_freg(L, rs1);
          when sp_func_movfp2i =>
            write_reg(L, Rtype_rd); write(L, string'(", "));
            write_freg(L, rs1);
          when sp_func_movi2fp =>
            write_freg(L, Rtype_rd); write(L, string'(", "));
            write_reg(L, rs1);
```

I can't understand what the code is trying to do here. Can you tell me what it does? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a complete correct VHDL fragment, so probably, no. The second chunk is part of a case statement though.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The complete code is too large, that's why I didn't put it in here. I want to understand what is happening in that case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those code snippets are pieces of procedures that write debug information on the screen when you run a simulation of a DLX processor.

The `when` clauses are per instruction type, so the procedure writes different debug information depending on the intruction that has been fetched from the program memory.

Here's an example of what you should see on the console when you run a simulation:

```
# DLX_bus_monitor: Command I-fetch from 00000010, word
# DLX_bus_monitor: Ready, instruction 1440FFF8 [ BNEZ     R2, -8 ]
```

In the example above, the `when` clauses from your code sample write the text that goes inside the brackets, after the instruction name.